# Android icon has white border on Pixel 3XL

Tags: android, android-studio, android-launcher

I'm trying to implement a launcher icon for an Android app. I'm using Android Studio's New Image Asset capability to create the icon from an image file and it works in most places except for the later Pixels.

On the Pixel 3XL, it looks like the following figure. The icon with a round white border around it.

[image: Pixel 3XL]

On the Pixel 2, it looks the same

[image: Pixel 2]

But on an original Pixel, it looks right:

[image: Pixel]

I created the icon assets using the Android Studio New Image Asset capability. Selecting the image icon as shown in the following figure:

[image]

Then I set the background to the background color for the icon:

[image: image background]

Based on what the UI shows, the icons all look right and Android Studio is supposed to generate the right files for all target platforms. Can someone please help me understand what I need to do to get rid of that white border on later phones?

Comment: Try a different launcher on your Pixel 3XL, it might just be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

You should add ic_launcher_foreground.xml and ic_launcher_background.xml to drawable file in your project. As far as I get it, you've try to make red background then add red backgorund layout you have only foreground image in this way. Btw that is not a bug that is a feature :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you please be more specific? The project has a ic_launcher_background.xml file in the project's `android\app\src\main\res\values` folder

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ic_launcher_background">#FF4C4C</color>
</resources>```

Comment: @johnwargo Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm currently facing the same issue.

Comment: yes, I just paid someone on Fivrr to make me an adaptive icon.